# What does the "e=True" argument mean in Maya Python?

Tags: python, maya

I'm a beginner to Python (and Maya for Python) and stumbled upon a script that could help me create a tool for use in Maya. In this script I encountered the bool e=true and google does not really help in this case. What does this argument do in this function? Thanks in advance.

`cmds.window(window, e=True, width=10, height=450, sizeable=False,resizeToFitChildren=True, topLeftCorner=[250, 250])`

## EDIT:

I might not have formulated my question the best way, my apologies for that.
I wanted to know what the keyword argument "e=True" meant in this function written by Autodesk for Maya. After some trial and error I found out the "e" is an abbreviation for "Edit".
https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/maya2013_getting_started/index.html?url=files/Using_Python_in_Maya_Using_the_edit_flag_in_Python.htm,topicNumber=d30e45740

The tech doc of the Window function did not reveal what it meant, this was the reason for my question.
https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/window.html#flagdockingLayout

Comment: parameter passing by name...

Answer (score 0):

e is a keyword argument to the cmds.window function, and `e=True` means pass the boolean `True` to the function as that argument.

https://treyhunner.com/2018/04/keyword-arguments-in-python/